# Plot returning negative values when the function is positive

Tags: plotting, functions

I am trying to see if a function is positive or negative using Plot3D , when I used Plot3D it looks like the graph will have negative values since it shows values in the range of $-0.1$ but when I substitue in the function the values for which this happens I get that the function is positive . Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this .

The code is the Following :

```
Plot3D[{0, 
  ReplaceAll[-(1/(192 (-1 + Cot[θ])))
      Csc[θ]^3 (-4 b0 - 3 b1 + 96 r^2 - 48 b0 r^2 - 
      24 b1 r^2 + 8 b1 r^4 + 72 β + 12 b0 β + 
      8 b1 β - 48 b0 β^2 - 24 b1 β^2 + 
      28 b0 β^3 + 10 b1 β^4 + 
      8 r (3 b0 (-1 + β)^2 + 6 β + 
         b1 (2 - 3 β + β^3)) Cos[θ] + 
      4 (6 (-4 + 2 b0 + 
            b1) r^2 + β (4 b0 (3 - 2 β) β - 
            3 (8 + b1 β (-2 + β^2)))) Cos[2 θ] - 
      24 b0 r Cos[3 θ] - 16 b1 r Cos[3 θ] - 
      48 r β Cos[3 θ] + 
      48 b0 r β Cos[3 θ] + 
      24 b1 r β Cos[3 θ] - 
      24 b0 r β^2 Cos[3 θ] - 
      8 b1 r β^3 Cos[3 θ] + 4 b0 Cos[4 θ] + 
      3 b1 Cos[4 θ] + 24 β Cos[4 θ] - 
      12 b0 β Cos[4 θ] - 8 b1 β Cos[4 θ] + 
      4 b0 β^3 Cos[4 θ] + 
      2 b1 β^4 Cos[4 θ] - 144 r Sin[θ] + 
      32 b0 r^3 Sin[θ] - 144 r β Sin[θ] + 
      144 b0 r β Sin[θ] + 
      72 b1 r β Sin[θ] - 
      72 b0 r β^2 Sin[θ] - 
      24 b1 r β^3 Sin[θ] + 24 Sin[2 θ] - 
      48 r^2 Sin[2 θ] - 48 β Sin[2 θ] - 
      24 b0 β Sin[2 θ] - 16 b1 β Sin[2 θ] + 
      48 b0 β^2 Sin[2 θ] + 
      24 b1 β^2 Sin[2 θ] - 
      24 b0 β^3 Sin[2 θ] - 
      8 b1 β^4 Sin[2 θ] + 48 r Sin[3 θ] + 
      48 r β Sin[3 θ] - 
      48 b0 r β Sin[3 θ] - 
      24 b1 r β Sin[3 θ] + 
      24 b0 r β^2 Sin[3 θ] + 
      8 b1 r β^3 Sin[3 θ] - 12 Sin[4 θ] + 
      24 β Sin[4 θ] + 12 b0 β Sin[4 θ] + 
      8 b1 β Sin[4 θ] - 
      24 b0 β^2 Sin[4 θ] - 
      12 b1 β^2 Sin[4 θ] + 
      12 b0 β^3 Sin[4 θ] + 
      4 b1 β^4 Sin[4 θ]), {r -> β*Sin[θ], 
    b0 -> a1, b1 -> a1}]}, {β, 1/2, 1}, {θ, Pi/4, Pi/2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{β, θ},
   θ >= ArcTan[β/(2 β - 1)]], 
 PlotLegends -> {"0", "F(β*Sin[θ])"}]
```

and $a_0$ and $a_1$ are the following :

```
a0=
-((6 (3 - 10 β + 8 β^2 - 6 β^4 + 4 β^5))/(
 1 - 12 β + 42 β^2 - 64 β^3 + 54 β^4 - 
  24 β^5 + 4 β^6))
a1=
(24 (1 - 4 β + 6 β^2 - 5 β^3 + 2 β^4))/(1 - 
 12 β + 42 β^2 - 64 β^3 + 54 β^4 - 
 24 β^5 + 4 β^6)
```

Comment: This is an artifact arising from `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.`.
An alternative would be `Show[{RegionPlot[f > 0 && regionFunction >= 0, vars], ContourPlot[regionFunction == 0, vars}]`, with `regionFunction = θ - ArcTan[β/(2 β - 1)` and `vars = Sequence[{β, 1/2, 1}, {θ, Pi/4, Pi/2}]`.

Comment: Is there any alternative so that I can have a plot that gives me the function not having negative values ? @Natas Also I am confused to what the code is doing could you enlighten me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could make the plot range smaller. The problem is that on the boundary of the region the value of the function is `ComplexInfinity`. E.g., `With[{eps = 10^-3}, Plot3D[f, {β, 1/2 + eps, 1}, {θ, Pi/4, Pi/2}, opts]`. Regarding my code either read the documentation or ask a specific question of what you don't understand.